# Seperate shortcut to run a program in administrative mode?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

I just installed StandaloneStack2 on Windows 7. I have a link to open it in my start menu to configure it which has to be run in administrative mode. I have a link pinned to my taskbar where it shouldn't be run in this mode as I have to go through the dialogue. Unfortunately, changing whether it runs in administrative mode (in the compatibility settings), seems to affect both shortcuts. I assume this is because compatibility mode settings are stored for the program, not for the shortcut

Is there a way to create a shortcut to run a program with different compatibility mode settings than those stored for the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right Click on shortcut
2. Select [Properties]
3. Select [Advanced...] button in the [Shortcut] tab
4. Check "Run as Administrator" checkbox
5. [Ok] button
6. [Ok] button

> P.S. Do not set "Run as Administrator"
>   from [Compatibility] tab :)

Answer (score 1):

If the question is regarding one particular program file, the quick-and-dirty solution is to copy the executable with another name so as to have the two shortcuts reference different files. The two files can then be assigned different compatibility mode settings.

Comment: Copy the executable??

Comment: well it's not really quick, but to be fair, it *is* dirty... :)

Comment: Any one having problems with this solution please see http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066999/.

Comment: May work, but ouch

Comment: I'm not too happy about this solution myself, but Windows places too many constraints upon compatibility mode settings.

Comment: As horrible as this is, this does appear to be the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Create an entirely new shortcut. There are a dozen different ways you can do this, but one explicit way is to rt-click ont he executable and choose Create Shortcut. Edit that shortcut to run as administrator, and then drag and drop alongside your existing non-administrator shortcut.

I had this problem myself; I needed a command prompt run as administrator, but didn't want *every* command prompt to run as administrator for obvious security reasons...

**UPDATE:**

I've just had reason to re-visit this type of issue, so I've had the opportunity to test various combinations...

I pinned a shortcut to the start menu (in Windows 7) and edited it to run as administrator - it works. I've also pinned it to my taskbar (not as Admin) and it also works as expected, and when I use the original start menu item is runs as expected (not as admin). I even created a copy of the original shortcut, which I made run as Admin, and again...it worked.

I think you need to re-visit this - my solution works, and I would argue makes more sense than copying executables.

Comment: Looks like a perfectly good solution to me. Perhaps the down-voter might like to record a comment to re-assure us that it wasn't down-voted for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Or perhaps other members might like to wade in with a comment...

Comment: I tried creating a new shortcut and it didn't work. Sorry, I thought I had added a comment on this.

Comment: It doesn't work? In what way?

Comment: When I edited the new shortcut, it edited the old one as well

Comment: Updated: It works... see above.

Comment: @CJM: Sorry, I tried this again, this time on a computer at work rather than home and it failed again.

Comment: Dmitry just explained what was going on

Answer (score 1):

In Vista, I use normal shortcuts, and select Run as Administrator from the context menu when needed.

Comment: Unfortunately the program runs without that option - it just doesn't work properly